# How do I install syncdrive?

Tags: apt

I am trying to install syncdrive in 14.04. It is showing the following error..

> Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libboost-filesystem1.49.0(>= 1.49.0-1)

So I installed the **libboost-filesystem1.54.0** version from synaptic, but still the error persists.

How to proceed?

Comment: `Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~thefanclub/+archive/grive-tools: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` means your Internet connection is probably not working, because you can't contact launchpad.net.  Try again.

Comment: Yes, The error was with the internet connection..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install grive-tools
```

After installation open **Dash/menu** and search for 'Grive Setup' or type `sudo grive-setup` in Terminal to configure Google Drive account for Grive.

Comment: Can you tell me how to install syncdrive in ubuntu 14.04 using command line?

Answer (score 2):

To install in 14.04 x64 open terminal and run:

```
    #download unmet requirements
    wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/boost1.49/libboost-filesystem1.49.0_1.49.0-4_amd64.deb
    wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/boost1.49/libboost-system1.49.0_1.49.0-4_amd64.deb
    wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/boost1.49/libboost-program-options1.49.0_1.49.0-4_amd64.deb
    #download latest version of syncdrive
    wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/157408170/syncdrive_0.9-1b~trusty~NoobsLab.com_all.deb
    #add gambas and syncdrive in case owner updates it soon
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/pear-apps
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/gambas3
    sudo apt-get update
    #install latest gambas
    sudo apt-get install gambas3
    #finally install all required packages and feel happy as a clam
    sudo dpkg -i syncdrive*.deb libboost*.deb
```

You can also copy all commands it into a .sh file using gedit allow executing and run it from a folder
I hope this is useful to all Gdrive and SyncDrive users
Cheers.

source: http://syncdrive.fr/?p=883